# Launch Intent from URL not working

Tags: android

I made a test Android app that I am trying to have launch when the browser hits the URL "blargh://yolo". But it is not working; instead the browser just does a google search.

It is a brand new project created by Eclipse/ADT; the only thing I've edited is the manifest, which is below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.testurlscheming"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.testurlscheming.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="blargh" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>
    </application>
```

Comment: How are you testing this? If you are entering `blargh://yolo` in the address bar, that is not a valid test. If you are clicking on a link in a Web page that links to `blargh://yolo`, that *is* a valid test.

Comment: you also don't have anything that is similar to your URL "template", so it will capture any url this way.

Comment: @CommonsWare was just testing by typing in, will try with a link and report back in a second

Comment: @CommonsWare Wow awesome, it does work with a link! Thanks! Didn't realize I was just testing this wrong - should I just delete the question?

Comment: @CommonsWare Do you know if it works from a redirect? The purpose of this whole thing is for OAuth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some Web browsers, like the AOSP Browser app, treat the address bar differently than it does hyperlinks. Hyperlinks route through a check for who handles `ACTION_VIEW` for that URL. The address bar is assumed to be something relevant for the Browser app; if it does not recognize it, it conducts a search, just as if you had typed `blargh yolo`.

> Do you know if it works from a redirect?

I would hope so. However, this may be browser-dependent. I would hope that browser makers follow the lead of Browser (and, over time, Chrome), but that's not guaranteed.

Comment: Note to future readers: the scheme must be listed in your manifest in all lower case, because the browser lower-cases the scheme before launching the intent. This frustrated me to no end just now.